# Assigning column names based on multiple parts of str.split

Tags: python, pandas, split

I have a pandas dataframe with column names that look like this

```
blah.stuff_I_want.more_I_want.blah.blah.blah
```

I am trying to keep only `stuff_I_want.more_I_want`

I tried

```
cols = df.columns.str.split('.', expand=True)[1:2]
    
df.columns = np.where(cols.notna(), cols, df.columns)
```

But I got the following error

```
NotImplementedError: isna is not defined for MultiIndex
```

I am not sure how to select multiple parts of the split. The `notna()` is needed to prevent renaming columns who do not have '.' in them to NAN.
How can I make this work? Or is there a better approach?

Comment: `cols = df.columns.str.split('.', expand=True)[0][1:3];  '.'.join(cols)` ????

Comment: that gave me the error `TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, float found`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [df.rename(columns=function_name, inplace=True)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html)

```
def convert(name):
    parts = name.split('.')
    name = '.'.join(parts[1:3])
    return name

df.rename(columns=convert, inplace=True)
```

You can use `if/else` to skip some conversions (ie when there is only one word)

```
def convert(name):
    parts = name.split('.')
    if len(parts) > 1:
         name = '.'.join(parts[1:3])
    return name
```

---

Minimal working example

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'blah.stuff_I_want.more_I_want.blah.blah.blah': [],
    'A': [],
    'A.B': [],
    'A.B.C': [],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def convert(name):
    parts = name.split('.')
    if len(parts) > 1:
         name = '.'.join(parts[1:3])
    return name

print(df.columns)

df.rename(columns=convert, inplace=True)

print(df.columns)
```

Result

```
# before
Index(['blah.stuff_I_want.more_I_want.blah.blah.blah', 'A', 'A.B', 'A.B.C'], dtype='object')

# after
Index(['stuff_I_want.more_I_want', 'A', 'B', 'B.C'], dtype='object')
```